# upgrading to bitcoin 0.10.2 fails

Tags: installation

i am attempting to upgrade my bitcoin client on debian wheezy. i have been following [the docs for this version](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md) and i installed berkley db to `${BITCOIN_ROOT}/db4` as directed. that went fine, but now when i run `./configure` it says the wrong version of berkleydb is installed:

```
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fvisibility=hidden... yes
checking for Berkeley DB C++ headers... default
configure: error: Found Berkeley DB other than 4.8, required for portable wallets (--with-incompatible-bdb to ignore or --disable-wallet to disable wallet functionality)
```

i also found that `autogen.sh` does not exist in the bitcoin root dir so i was unable to run it as per the instructions.

i already have berkley db 5 installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep db5
ii  db5.1-util                                   5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Utilities
ii  libdb5.1:amd64                               5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.1++:amd64                             5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries for C++ [runtime]
ii  libdb5.1++-dev                               5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries for C++ [development]
ii  libdb5.1-dev                                 5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [development]
ii  libdb5.1-java                                5.1.29-5                           all          Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries for Java
ii  libdb5.1-java-jni:amd64                      5.1.29-5                           amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries for Java
ii  libkdb5-6:amd64                              1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2               amd64        MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Kerberos database
ii  libsybdb5:amd64                              0.91-2+deb7u1                      amd64        libraries for connecting to MS SQL and Sybase SQL servers
```

i don't want to remove db5 because other programs i rely on are using it:

```
 $ apt-cache rdepends db5.1-util
db5.1-util
Reverse Depends:
  subversion
    db5.1-util:i386
  subversion
    db5.1-util:i386
  libapache2-svn
    db5.1-util:i386
```

**how can i get bitcoin to install with berkley db 4.8 when 5.1 is already installed elsewhere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow compatibility of your wallet.dat file with other bitcoind installations, it's strongly recommended to use bdb 4.8.

Nevertheless, you can disable the db4.8 check by adding `--with-incompatible-bdb` during configure.

Better would be to manually install berkley db 4.8 in a isolated path and compile bitcoin-core with something similar to:

`CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I<your-bdb4.8-path>/include"
LIBS="$LIBS -L<your-bdb4.8-path>/lib"`

But this would probably require some makefile tweaking.

Comment: thanks! i have already installed berkley db 4.8 under `${BITCOIN_ROOT}/db4` (i followed the instructions in `docs/builld-unix.md`) i will try and compile bitcoin-core with the flags you suggest. if i have problems i will update the op.

Comment: nope - its still coming up with the same errors when i run `./configure` even with `CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I${BITCOIN_ROOT}/db4/include"` and with `LIBS="$LIBS -L${BITCOIN_ROOT}/db4/lib"`

Comment: If you have troubles using different include/ lib/ dirs for bdb you might try `--with-incompatible-bdb` and take the risk of not being able to use your wallet on bitcoin-core installations with bdb4.8.

Comment: ya i did that :) i can always import my private keys into other wallets so its no big problem for me